# Confusion between links menu types and categories

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu, module-display, category

I'm facing an issue with Joomla 3.9.16.

- I have created many categories, with sub-categories ; here is my organisation :

[image: Categories]

- I created corresponding menus and sub-menus to be able to put some modules when displaying the page :

[image: Menus]

The menus have **exactly** the same organization than the categories. Since some categories only have one article, some menu ("Que décrire ?", "Que prélever ?",...) are "**single article**" menu.

- I have one module named "**Autres étapes**" only displayed on Larynx submenus:

[image: Module]

***On frontend :***
You can go on "Larynx" category there :

Then you select "**Larynx**", then "**Anatomie - orientation**" : then you can see the module "Autres étapes" on the right. It's OK. The URL is :

But : if you go to "**Que décrire ?**" or "**Que prélever ?**", it ***does not*** show the module. The URL is now :

It seems that Anatomie-Orientation is going to a **link menu** (URL does not show any ID) whereas "que décrire ?" is going to the **category** (URL showing *17-que-decrire*, 17 is the ID of the category "que décrire ?"). I'm misleading something about the organization of Joomla I think... But what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this:

> Since some categories only have one article, some menu ("Que décrire ?", "Que prélever ?",...) are "single article" menu.

You don't have a menu item created for these categories.

Comment: Oh thank you you solved this ! Another question nevertheless : if I put thoses menus as "List of Articles" it works as you said. But if my module "Autres étapes", reproducing my menu, now when i click on "Que décrire ?" it leads me to the list of one article, whereas I would like to be pointed directly to this single article.
What would be the best solution ? Duplicating the menu, one with list of category and one with single article (for the module) ?

Comment: If you want category link to point to a single article, that is not possible without custom coding.